# How can I copy bitmap to another bitmap without using createBitmap() and copy() on Android?

Tags: android, bitmap

I have two bitmaps and I create them in onCreate().

```
Bitmap bmp1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),id);
Bitmap bmp2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),id);
```

bmp1 and bmp2 are same. I modify bmp2 in my application. After my job is done, I click "Clear" button. I am trying to copy bmp1 (clean image) to bmp2(changed image) when I click "Clear" button. But I don't want to use createBitmap() or copy() function. Because these are create new Bitmap objects. I want to use only my two bitmaps (bmp1 and bmp2). How can I copy bmp1 to bmp2? I search google but everbody do this with createBitmap() or copy().

Thanks.

Comment: How about `Canvas.drawBitmap()`?

Comment: @Alan, I draw my image with drawBitmap(). After I modified image (bmp2) I need clean image (bmp1). In my scenario bmp1 keeps always clean and bmp2 is always on screen. When I need clean image I copy bmp1 to bmp2. But how?

Comment: If you are making photo editing app or alike, you can use `Canvas` on the bmp2, and make use of `Canvas.save()` and `Canvas.restore()`

Comment: Thank you @Alan. But I'm new on Android. Can you provide example. I use surfaceView for my image modification. How should I use it?

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618355/how-to-blit-in-android

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I solved my problem

First I created bmp1,bmp2 and canvas for bmp2:

```
bmp1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(cont.getResources(), R.drawable.image);
bmp2 = bmp1.copy(bmp1.getConfig(), true);
canvasBmp2 = new Canvas( bmp2 );
```

When I want to copy bmp1 to bmp2:

```
canvasBmp2.drawBitmap(bmp1, 0, 0, null);

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
{
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp2, 0, 0, null);
}
```

Comment: What if, the new Bitmap should be in a difference size and have Config.RGB_565 ?