# using opencv in android

Tags: android, image, opencv, bitmap

I have a code which captures/selects an image and sets it to an imageview. What I want is, store this image in a variable, pass it to a function and set an integer output in the textView. Now, if I manually use an image which is stored in drawable (converting into bitmap and then mat), I get the desired result. But, when I try to use the bitmap image which is being taken dynamically from the camera/gallery (after converting into mat), an exception arises. From what I understand, The captured/selected image is not being converted or stored in a variable as it shows bmp=null. 
The codes are: 
For capturing the image:

```
public void onCaptureImageResult(Intent data) {
       Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes);

        File destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");

        FileOutputStream fo;
        try {
            destination.createNewFile();
            fo = new FileOutputStream(destination);
            fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
            fo.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
     thumbnail1=thumbnail;
        ivImage.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
    }
```

For selecting the image:

```
public void onSelectFromGalleryResult(Intent data) {

     bm = null;
    if (data != null) {
        try {
            bm = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), data.getData());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    ivImage.setImageBitmap(bm);
}
```

For processing the image and setting the output:

```
   public void countDents(Mat src) {
    int count = 0;
    Mat source;
    source = src;
    int cnt = 0, cnt2 = 0;
    Mat middle, destination1, destination2;
    List<MatOfPoint> contours1 = new ArrayList<>();
    List<MatOfPoint> contours2 = new ArrayList<>();
    middle = new Mat();
    destination1 = new Mat();
    destination2 = new Mat();
    /*Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.car);
    Utils.bitmapToMat(img, source);*/
    Imgproc.cvtColor(source, middle, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);
    Imgproc.equalizeHist(middle, middle);
   // ivImage.setImageBitmap(img);
    Imgproc.threshold(middle, destination1, 150, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY);
    Imgproc.threshold(middle, destination2, 150, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY_INV);
    Imgproc.findContours(destination1, contours1, new Mat(), Imgproc.RETR_LIST, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
    Imgproc.findContours(destination2, contours2, new Mat(), Imgproc.RETR_LIST, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
  //  Utils.matToBitmap(destination2, img);
    for (int i = 0; i < contours1.size(); i++) {
        if (Imgproc.contourArea(contours1.get(i)) > 5 && Imgproc.contourArea(contours1.get(i)) < 200) {
            cnt++;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < contours2.size(); i++) {
        if (Imgproc.contourArea(contours2.get(i)) > 5 && Imgproc.contourArea(contours2.get(i)) < 200) {
            cnt2++;


            count = cnt + cnt2;
            String c = Integer.toString(count);
            TVdents.setText(c);

        }
    }
```

onClick function for where function is being called:

```
    public void onClick(View v) {
            Utils.bitmapToMat(thumbnail1,tmp);
            Utils.bitmapToMat(bm,tmp);
            countDents(tmp);

        }
```

> 07-25 11:19:21.727 19363-19363/com.example.smartlayer.imageprocessing
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                           Process: com.example.smartlayer.imageprocessing, PID: 19363
>                                                                                           java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bmp == null
>                                                                                               at org.opencv.android.Utils.bitmapToMat(Utils.java:90)
>                                                                                               at org.opencv.android.Utils.bitmapToMat(Utils.java:102)
>                                                                                               at
>   com.example.smartlayer.imageprocessing.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:80)
>                                                                                               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4785)
>                                                                                               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19884)
>                                                                                               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
>                                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                               at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
>                                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)

If there is any discrepancy  int the question, the code or way of asking, please let me know, I'll rectify.

Comment: You say "**bmp=null**". However, I don't see a `bmp` in the code - please indicate where this null image occurs.

Comment: Its in the standard utils class, not my code. It shows on the logcat when exception occurs:  **java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bmp == null**

Comment: Please post your LogCat then. When you follow the stack trace, what line in your code gives an error?

Comment: done. The error is in the line where the function is being called. In function onClick() {    Utils.bitmapToMat(thumbnail1,tmp);} In different alterrations I tried, I conclude that **tmp** is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the problem is that `thumbnail1` is `null`; if it was `tmp`, you would see [`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: mat == null`](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/java/generator/src/java/android%2BUtils.java#L92), according to the source code on GitHub.

So, what I think is the problem is that in `onCaptureImageResult()` after the assignment:

```
thumbnail1 = thumbnail;
```

Things get garbage collected and `thumbnail1` is no longer valid. So, what you can do is take a copy of `thumbnail` by [doing this instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23683075/1270789):

```
thumbnail1 = thumbnail.copy(thumbnail.getConfig(), true);
```

(I'm not 100% sure this will work, though...)

Comment: This worked! But if I press the button many times in a row, the app pauses. Although, I don't think this is the reason. Thank you so much! :)

Comment: Note I had a typo in my code, but since you got things working you must have fixed it yourself. Glad I could help.

Comment: Yes, that bmp1 thing. I got it though. Thanks again.